# Tar command failed when compressing the sql file

Tags: sql-server, linux, unix

I am trying to compress one sql file using the below tar command. But it is getting failed without any warnings or exceptions in the error log.

> Syntax: tar --warning=no-file-changed -zcvf $bkpdir${hadoopdb}*mysqldb*$bkpday.sql.tar.gz $bkpdir${hadoopdb}*mysqldb*$bkpday.sql

Is there any way to catch the error when executing the above command.

My Code snippet looks like this.

```
tar --warning=no-file-changed -zcvf $bkpdir${hadoopdb}_mysqldb_$bkpday.sql.tar.gz $bkpdir${hadoopdb}_mysqldb_$bkpday.sql



 if [ "$?" != 0 ]
   then
      echo "Error while compressing the db backup file"
      errmsg
      exit 1
   fi
```

Error Message: Error while compressing the db backup file

`TAR Version : 1.23`

Please do the needful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive the proper syntax for integer comparison is:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
```

The `!=` operator is used for pattern matching.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

---

You can direct the error output to a file as well.

> tar --warning=no-file-changed -zcvf
>   $bkpdir${hadoopdb}*mysqldb*$bkpday.sql.tar.gz
>   $bkpdir${hadoopdb}*mysqldb*$bkpday.sql 2> tar_sql.err

will write errors to the file tar_sql.err.

---

You can also turn on -e mode. In this mode any command your script runs which returns a non-zero exitcode will cause your script to itself terminate immediately with an error.

You can do that in your shebang line:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
```

Comment: Modified the script with "-ne" and added "-e" parameter script ran successfully.

Comment: But this happen when running the shell script using cronjob with exception **Error Message: Error while compressing the db backup file**

Comment: Thats something you have to track down.  Crontabs run as different users.  Does the user have permission to write in the indicated directory?  There might also be a environment or path issue.  You might have the error message you print also print your substitution variables to make sure they are being resolved correctly.

Comment: Yes !! Account has proper privileges whenever it fails we use to run this script manually and it works. But sometimes it fails with cronjob scheduled.

Comment: A thought.  If you can change the nice level of the script you can raise its priority so that the OS elevates the processing power to processing the .tar file.

Comment: What is the shell of the crontab user running the script?  Your script interpreter directive should match ie, bash or shell

#!/bin/bash   #!/bin/ksh

Comment: i am using #!/bin/bash

Comment: i couldn't able to share the script here can u please provide me ur mail id. My script is too long can't fit in this comment.